# Grothendieck's schematic point of view of regular polyhedra

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polyhedra

I am asking this question out of curiousity.

Wikipedia lists Grothendieck's main mathematical achievements, [the last](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck#Major_mathematical_topics_.28from_R.C3.A9coltes_et_Semailles.29) of which is

> [a] "Schematic" or "arithmetic" point of view for regular polyhedra and regular configurations of all kinds.

Can anyone please elaborate on that? Are there books written on this topic?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can find some further information in _Esquisse d'un programme_ (English translation [here](http://matematicas.unex.es/~navarro/res/esquisseeng.pdf)), but I haven't read it myself.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I just skimmed. Thanks a lot. I will accept it as an answer if you write it as an answer although the culture here is to wait a little bit to see if there are further references.

Comment: I'm sure if you wait long enough, someone who actually knows something about the subject might answer! (You could also ask at MathOverflow.)

Comment: @ZhenLin, okay, I will wait for some time. Thanks for the comment.